# Returning a private variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I don't know why `console.log(Set.current_index)` shows `0` instead of `3`.

```
var Set = (function() {
    var set = [];
    var index = 0;

    function contains(set, e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            if (set[i] === e) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    var add = function(e) {
        if (!contains(set, e)) {
            set[index++] = e;
        }
    }

    var show = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            console.log(set[i]);
        }
    }

    return {
        add: add,
        show: show,
        current_index: index
    };
})();​

Set.add(20);
Set.add(30);
Set.add(40);
Set.show();
console.log(Set.current_index);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written `current_index` just gets the *initial* value of `index` - it doesn't mirror any changes to that value because that variable is of *primitive* type.

If you have a 'reference type' (i.e. an object or array) then changes to its contents become visible in any other variable that references the same object.  That doesn't happen with primitive types, they're copied "by value" into the new variables, and changes to the original variable don't affect the copy.

You need to make `current_index` into a *function* that returns the current value of `index`, or write it as a `getter` which allows you to treat `.index` as a read-only property by invisibly calling a function to return the current value.

For an example of the latter method (which requires ES5, or shims to replicate the functionality) see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WAwUg/, which replaces your current `return` block with this:

```
var interface = {
    add: add,
    show: show
};

Object.defineProperty(interface, 'index', {
    get: function() {
        return index;
    },
    enumerable: true
});

return interface;
```

Comment: Or just don't use a private `index` variable but the public property in the `add` method

Comment: @Bergi I suspect that the private encapsulation is important to the design of this function.

Comment: Yes, possible. The OP needs to decide what he wants

Comment: Ok, I get it. But I don't understand `it doesn't mirror any changes to that value because that variable is of primitive type`.

Comment: @enrmarc I've added some additional text.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript always passes by value except when a variable refers to an object. So your initialization of **current_index** just gets the initial value of **index** rather than permanently pointing to the variable, so after that initialization, the two variables are on their separate ways therefore incrementing **index** doesn't increment **current_index**.